# Receive MAP in a string variable

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I was wondering how set the variable list as String.

```
const emails = [
  {"ID": "11109", "VALUE": "financesss@123m.com", "TYPE_ID": "EMAIL"},
  {"ID": "13429", "VALUE": "teste@testeeeee.com", "TYPE_ID": "EMAIL"}];

const list = emails.map(VALUE => VALUE.VALUE)

console.log(list) //desired result:: financesss@123m.com,teste@testeeeee.com
console.log(typeof list); //string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join an array into a single string with a delimiter by doing

```
const list = emails.map(VALUE => VALUE.VALUE).join(",");
```

The default delimiter for `join` is a comma (`,`) so you can express this as `arr.join()` should you wish.

See here for a definition of `join`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join